# Git pull request branch name in teamcity

Tags: git, teamcity, pull-request

I configured git pull requests my teamcity server for QA testing environment. If I use TeamCity [feature branching integration](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Working+with+Feature+Branches), I can get branch name with this property: `%teamcity.build.branch%`.

When [use pull request](http://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/02/automatically-building-pull-requests-from-github-with-teamcity/), the `%teamcity.build.branch%` property  return pull request number (1,2,3 etc).

How can I get pull request branch name?

Answer (score 7):

Parameter **teamcity.build.branch** is a logical branch, i.e. it's a part of a branch from your branch specification matched by *.

There is another parameter **teamcity.build.vcs.branch.<VCS root ID>** which contains full Git branch name. Seems this is what you need.

You can read more on this in documentation: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Predefined+Build+Parameters#PredefinedBuildParameters-BranchRelatedParameters

Comment: teamcity.build.vcs.branch.<VCS root ID> gives me refs/pull/1/head, but actual branch name is feature-tc

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that anything akin to [`SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_SOURCEBRANCH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#systempullrequestsourcebranch) is available in TeamCity, but perhaps you can make use of the "logical branch name" instead? In TC, this directly corresponds to the substring matched by the `*` placeholder that you probably have added in your **VCS Root** -> **Branch Specification**.

Caveat: some articles advice you to have an extra **Branch Spec.** like `+:refs/pull/*/head` and `+:refs/pull/*/merge`. The effect of that is: if "42" happens to be the Pull Request id, the full ref name will be `refs/pull/42/head` and thus TeamCity will match and show only `42` as the (logical) branch name for both the merging branch *and* builds of the merge result.

One workaround to this is to make the asterisk match a *long-enough* substring of the (PR) ref name to be meaningful *to you*. Another is to use brackets to include more of the ref. Your requirements will depend a bit on your branch naming conventions.

Example:

> **Default branch:**
>
> ```
> refs/heads/develop
> ```
>
> **Branch Specification**:
>
> ```
> +:refs/(pull/*/merge)
> +:refs/heads/*
> ```

...will show branches like `pull/42/merge`, `master`, `hotfix/1.2.3` etc.